# Asynchronous HTTP Response Message

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest, asp.net-web-api, http-headers

so this has been bugging since a while. I am not sure why my Http Response Message step is skipped by Visual Studio Debugger. This is the code i have currently:

```
public async void APIcall()          
{                
    HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
    HttpRequestMessage requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "http://xxxx");
    requestMessage.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/json");
    requestMessage.Headers.Add("ContentType", "application/json");
    requestMessage.Headers.Add("RequestMessageGUID", "xxxxxx");
    HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.SendAsync(requestMessage);
    string result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    Console.WriteLine(result);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Please give your suggestions and help to resolve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should avoid doing `async` on `void` methods unless it's an event handler. Use `Task` even if you are not returning anything.

Next you are assuming that you will always get content from your request.

You should check first that there is something to get

When you use async on void methods your exceptions are not going to get caught. That is probably why it kept skipping as you said. It was probably error out.

```
private static HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
public async Task APIcall() {
    try {
        HttpRequestMessage requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "http://xxxx");
        requestMessage.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/json");
        requestMessage.Headers.Add("ContentType", "application/json");
        requestMessage.Headers.Add("RequestMessageGUID", "xxxxxx");
        HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.SendAsync(requestMessage);
        if (response.Content.Headers.ContentLength.GetValueOrDefault() > 0) {
            string result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            Console.WriteLine(result);
        } else {
            Console.WriteLine(response.StatusCode);
        }
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```